# PWA - Cache and load same appshell for different seo-friendly urls

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps, cacheapi

We are consumer internet and have SEO friendly urls: www.xyz.com/user-1, www.xyz.com/user-2, www.xyz.com/user-n. Technically these are all user pages with different url's. And we need to load only one html file (app-shell) for all these cases.

What I want to achieve is that:

1. Go to www.xyz.com/user-1 page, cache the html (app-shell) file.
2. Navigate to www.xyz.com/user-2 page, get the html response from cache of www.xyz.com/user-1 ( since it is the same app-shell ).

I couldn't achieve this because, the 'match' method of cache api works on url request object, and I couldn't manipulate it. Is there a way where I can manipulate the url request object? Or is there a workaround for it?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own response if you want. However I think you are describing the classic SPA architecture. There you would have an app shell and fill in the main content area on the client-side, either by rendering the markup in the browser or appending pre-rendered markup from the server.
You might want to check out the sw templating strategy as a possible place to start -> https://jakearchibald.com/2014/offline-cookbook/#serviceworker-side-templating